# invalid input from the user using loop

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make a while loop when the input from the user is invalid meaning it is not "yes" or "no" so that the question would appear again. i would appreciate it if you could help me out here!!! thanks(i have deleted most of the code except for the problem because it was too long !!)
code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ShowWhatYouKnow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rd = new Random();
        String ready;
        int guess;

        int[] dice = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to dice game!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-6 and win $50!!");
        System.out.println("Are you ready??");
        ready = key.nextLine();
// trying to do a do while here so if the user inputs the invalid option this would accur again and again
/*
System.out.println("invalid input !");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-6 and win $50!!");
        System.out.println("Are you ready??");
        ready = key.nextLine();
*/
        if (ready.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Let The Game Begin!!");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
          
            }
        } else if(ready.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            System.out.println("You Exited The Program!! Bye!");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        

    

}
}
```

Comment: maybe look at adding another else? This looks suspiciously like a UNI/School assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to solve your problem: the question will appear again if the input from user is not "yes" or "no". You could write the main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rd = new Random();
    String ready;
    int guess;

    int[] dice = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    System.out.println("Welcome to dice game!");
    do {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-6 and win $50!!");
        System.out.println("Are you ready??");
        ready = key.nextLine();
    } while (!ready.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !ready.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
    if (ready.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Let The Game Begin!!");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

    } else if (ready.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("You Exited The Program!! Bye!");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an infinite loop and break it when the input is correct

```
    while (true) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-6 and win $50!!");
            System.out.println("Are you ready??");
            ready = key.nextLine();
            if (ready.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Let The Game Begin!!");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                break;
            } else if (ready.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                System.out.println("You Exited The Program!! Bye!");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid input !");
            }
        }
```